# I am unable to loop and create multiple events

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0;i<daysofweek.length;i++){

$("input[name=" + daysofweek[i] + "]").change(function(){ if($(this).is(':checked')){ $("#" + daysofweek[i] + "_content").show();}else{  $("#" + daysofweek[i] + "_content").hide(); }     })   //loop through all days of the week creating the event that show/hides days
}
```

I dont know what to call it, but what I want is to have this change function for each day of the week.

Is there something wrong with my concatenation? The loop is definitely working and I'm getting the values from the array.

Comment: What isn't working?  It isn't clear from the text above.  Also is it possible to have multiple day's of the week checkboxes checked at once in your UI?

Comment: sorry. The change event is not happening.... I mean if I manually write the days in the selectors it works. So Im thinking it's my concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a function inside a loop in Javascript and the function uses the loop variable, it captures the *variable itself*, not the current value. So at the end of the loop, the variable is the last value that `i` reaches. You need to wrap it all in another function and pass the current value of the variable to that.

```
for(i=0;i<daysofweek.length;i++){
  (function(i) {
    $("input[name=" + daysofweek[i] + "]").change(function() { 
      if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        $("#" + daysofweek[i] + "_content").show();
      } else {
        $("#" + daysofweek[i] + "_content").hide(); 
      }     
    });
  })(i);   //loop through all days of the week creating the event that show/hides days
}
```

Comment: This certainly works, but it could be improved by reusing a single named function, instead of constructing an identical anonymous function in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You lose the correct value of `i`, because it is not scoped in the `for` loop.

You could [use `$.each()` instead](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), which creates a closure:

```
$.each(daysofweek, function(i, val) {
    $("input[name=" + daysofweek[i] + "]").change(function() {
        if ( this.checked ) {
            $("#" + daysofweek[i] + "_content").show();
        } else {
            $("#" + daysofweek[i] + "_content").hide();
        }
    }); //loop through all days of the week creating the event that show/hides days
});
```

Also, I changed `$(this).is(':checked')` to `this.checked`. It is much faster.

You can also simplify a bit [by using `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of `show/hide`.

```
$.each(daysofweek, function(i, val) {
    $("input[name=" + daysofweek[i] + "]").change(function() {
        $("#" + daysofweek[i] + "_content").toggle( this.checked );
    }); //loop through all days of the week creating the event that show/hides days
});
```

Comment: If you're using `each`, you can just write `val` instead of `daysofweek[i]`.

Comment: @Chuck: Very true. Either parameter could be closed around, and `val` would save a property lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't block-scoped in JavaScript, so the functions you're passing to the change() method will all have the same value of `i`.